# How to download 1.4.13 version of gnupg in linux server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, gpg, gnu

Maybe this problem is not good, but I have tried it for two days. Still no success. I want to download the 1.4.13 version of `gnupg`, but I found that the various websites of `gnupg` are not accessible. I saw *gnupg* on *github*, but when I use `git clone -b 1.4.13 https://gitee.com/mirrors/GnuPG.git`, it shows that there is no 1.4.13, which is very crashing. I'm doing some experiments on the side channel. In the experiment, I want to use vulnerabilities in the encryption algorithm of gnupg version 1.4.13 to infer data. Other versions fix this problem, so there is no way to use it.

The server used is  `Linux mprc-PowerEdge-R730 4.15.0-122-generic #124~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 16:08:36 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "various versions of gnugp are not accessible"? I looked at https://gnupg.org/download/index.html and the link for 1.4.23 works fine.

Comment: Thanks, But I am looking for 1.4.13. Not 1.4.23. I did not find 1.4.13 on this website

Comment: Oh, I see. Why do you need that particular version?

Comment: Thank you!  That version of the algorithm has a little loophole, I want to do some security experiments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to download the 1.4.13 version of `gnupg`

https://gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/gnupg/gnupg-1.4.13.tar.bz2

https://gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/gnupg/gnupg-1.4.13.tar.bz2.sig

Answer (score 1):

One way to find old source code for a popular open source program is to look at a distribution like Fedora Linux or Debian which has the concept of *pristine sources*. That is, the package includes an unmodified tar file from the upstream project. In this case, it happens that gnupgp 1.4.13 was part of F18, so you can download the corresponding source rpm from

https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/18/Everything/source/SRPMS/g/

You can then unpack the source RPM and get the original tar file.